# pandas to_numeric/to_* raising buffer error if input is a dataframe slice

Tags: python, debugging, pandas

applying the pandas to_numeric or to_datetime functions on dataframes the way I've read them being applied works fine if the input is a whole dataframe, but not if it is a slice of more than one column of a dataframe.

Am I doing something wrong or is this unintended behavior?

Consider:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50,5))
print(test_df.iloc[:25,2:4])
pd.to_numeric(test_df.iloc[:25, 2:4])
```

yields error

*ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)*

I am running pandas v17.0.0 on Anaconda stack (2.4) of Python 3.4.3.

Running to_numeric via apply on the dataframe iloc selection, ie

```
test_df.iloc[:25, 2:4].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

works fine.

This behavior above, ie on slices of dataframes, intentional?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will also not work on full dataframes (`pd.to_numeric(test_df)` will give the same error) as the `to_datetime` and `to_numeric` functions are only designed to work with 1-dimensional data (Series, 1D-array, list). See the [docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html).

So your approach of using `apply` is the correct one if you want to use this functions on several columns at the same time.

Comment: sorry... before posting i should have read docstring specifically. Didn't realize was only implemented on series objects...